# schema.org event syntax for all day events and subEvents

Tags: schema.org

Tried to Google out but came empty handed. I'm looking for a snippet containing example markup.

How should I mark all-day events?

How should I mark concerts having multiple performances with varying locations (for same data multiple start and end dates) aka. subEvents? This is what I tried:

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Event"><!-- section per event -->
    <a href="/test#event_17" id="event_17" itemprop="url">
        <h3><!-- visual title when and where -->
            <div itemprop="summary"><!-- summary what the event is for -->
                Summary text
            </div>

        </h3>
    </a>
    <span itemprop="location" class="location">
        Location name
    </span>
    <span itemprop="subEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Event">
        <a href="/test#event_17_1" id="event_17_1" itemprop="url">
            <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2014-09-15T15:00:00+03:00">00:00</time>
            —
            <time itemprop="endDate" datetime="2014-09-15T17:00:00+03:00">00:00</time>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span itemprop="subEvent" itemscope  itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Event">
        <a href="/test#event_17_2" id="event_17_2" itemprop="url">
            <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2014-10-10T20:00:00+03:00">00:00</time>
            —
            <time itemprop="endDate" datetime="2014-10-10T22:00:00+03:00">00:00</time>
        </a>
    </span>



    <div itemprop="description"><!-- details of the event -->
        Description
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: For all-day events I tried startDate 00:00:00 -> endDate startDate +1 day 00:00:00
 
`startdate: 2014-09-09T00:00:00+03:00`
`enddate: 2014-09-10T00:00:00+03:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based solely on http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

**How should I mark all-day events?**

For all day events it seems that the appropriate way is to give only datetime value. End date is not required.
2015/02/17

**How should I mark concerts having multiple performances with varying locations (for same data multiple start and end dates) aka. subEvents?**

Notice itemref to concert name.

```html
<h1 itemscope=""><span id="concertName" itemprop="name">Foo</h1>
<p>
   <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicEvent" itemref="concertName">
      <strong>Wed 3.12.2014</strong> 10:05
      <span itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
         <span itemprop="name">Concert Hall</span>
      </span>

      <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2014-12-03T10:05:00+02:00" />
      <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.example.com/concert/8" />
   </span>
   


   <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicEvent" itemref="concertName">
      <strong>Fri 26.12.2014</strong> 10:05 
      <span itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
         <span itemprop="name">Concert Hall</span>
      </span>
      <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2014-12-26T10:05:00+02:00" />
      <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.example.com/concert/8" />
   </span>
</p>
```